# Why does my view class not show up in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I added a custom view class with its own xib. In the xib, File's Owner -> Custom Class is set to "MyCustomView".

I added a blank view in my storyboard with class set to "MyCustomView"

When I run my app, I don't see my view being displayed properly. However, I do see `2013-03-01 16:52:48.283 Test[56785:c07] MyCustomView initWithCoder`

Any ideas what went wrong?

I have isolated this error here: http://bit.ly/YdDbqU

Thanks!

EDIT:

1. I turned off autolayout
2. I used the following:

   UIView *subview = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;
   subview.frame = self.myCustomViewInstance.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:subview];
3. Any everything worked!

Comment: What does "displayed properly" mean.  I see a blank, white, UIView, as it should be

Comment: @CodaFi well the xib has a few labels: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... I was referring to that xib being displayed on the white space of the main view

Answer (score 1):

You never actually load that xib -- setting the class in IB isn't enough. You still need to load the xib file, and set your controller's view to that view;

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "MyCustomView.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;
}
```

Comment: That worked! However, doesn't setting self.view mean that the entire FirstViewController's view (including its child, MyCustomView) is replaced? I added an extra label in FirstMainViewController at the bottom and now label can no longer be seen because the entire view is replaced. (I created a new commit "Added label but label now missing?", Would you mind taking a look again?)

Comment: @iaman00b, if you don't want the entire view replaced then add that view as a subview of self.view.

Answer (score 0):

1. I turned off autolayout
2. I used the following:

   UIView *subview = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil].lastObject; subview.frame = self.myCustomViewInstance.bounds; [self.view addSubview:subview];

Any everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class is a inherits from UIViewController.

```
@interface ClassName : UIViewController
```